# Amazon InApp purchase still runs in Sandbox mode after the application is purchased

Tags: amazon-web-services, in-app-purchase

I published my app with Amazon AppStore, but InApp Testing library still has PurchasingService.IS_SANDBOX_MODE set to true.

I am not using an Amazon device, which may explain why it happens.

- Is Amazon InApp purchasing meant to run on a non-Amazon device?
- If it runs, what need to be done to enable live testing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon In-App Purchasing API works on non-Amazon device.

Did you download your app from Amazon Appstore? Only the build downloaded from Amazon Appstore would run outside of sandbox mode.

You can test your app outside of sandbox mode with their [Live App Testing](https://developer.amazon.com/public/resources/development-tools/live-app-testing/docs/getting-started) service.

Comment: Thanks! this helps a a lot! Amazon's document did not metioned about this, and I was confused for a long time because PurchasingService.IS_SANDBOX_MODE is just a constant.